# Disqus not counting up comments correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, disqus

I'm currently using a plugin called 'Disqus' for comments on the website and it isn't 'counting' them up properly.

To get the comment counts to be correct I have to keep syncing them which is a pain.

I've read lots of stuff on the internet about it being easy to fix but I think it must be a case of 'easy when you know how'!

Here is an example:

It displays 5 comments here:

http://www.mac-nutrition.com/research-update-low-carbohydrate-diet-in-type-1-diabetes/

But on the actual page it displays 3 comments:

http://www.mac-nutrition.com/category/blogs/

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's showing 5 for me? Are you missing the nested comments / responses?

Comment: Hey! On http://www.mac-nutrition.com/category/blogs/ for the article *Research Update: Low carbohydrate diet in type 1 diabetes* it shows only 3 comments.

Comment: It is only when you open the article at http://www.mac-nutrition.com/research-update-low-carbohydrate-diet-in-type-1-diabetes/ then it shows 5 comments.